# How to showing result Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I'm trying to retrieve variable from jquery to my codeigniter controller.

My Jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#reservation').change(function(){
            var ids = $('#reservation').val();
            $.post ( "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/sia/index/",
             { date_search:ids },
             function(data){
                //what i need to do ??
             });
    });
});
```

My HTML

```
       <div class="input-group margin col-lg-3 col-xs-6 pull-right">
         <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" readonly="readonly" placeholder="Cari Berdasarkan Tanggal" name="date_search" id="reservation" />
       </div>
```

and here is my controller

```
     function index()
         {
           // How to retrieve date_search 
            $explode = explode('-',$date_search);
            $start_date = inggris_date($explode[0]);
            $end_date = inggris_date($explode[1]);
            $data['master'] = $this->db->query("select status,b.Nip,b.positioncode,a.start_date,a.ApprovedBy,c.OutletCode,a.Approvedby,a.IdAttendanceA,a.Alokasi,a.keterangan,a.files,b.FullName
            from Attendance_Alokasi a left join employee b on a.Nip = b.Nip
            left join outlet c on b.OutletCode = c.OutletCode
            where flag = '1' and (start_date >= '".$start_date."' and start_date <= '".$end_date."') and a.Nip = '".$Nip."'")->result();
        $data['judul'] = "Sia";
        $view = "sia/index";
        $controller = "sia";
        $this->get_view($data,$view,$controller);         
         }
```

How to retrieve `date_search:ids` in my controller and do `echo` ?.

Update.

When i do `alert(ids)` after i input `05/03/2016 - 05/03/2016` here is the result :
[image]

Comment: `$this->input->post('date_search')`

Comment: @RejoanulAlam what i need to do in this part `function(data){
                //what i need to do ??
             });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this you controller

```
 function index()
     {
        $date_search = $this->input->post('date_search'); 
        $explode = explode('-',$date_search);
        $sd = trim($explode[0]);
        $ed = trim($explode[1]);
        $start_date = inggris_date($sd);
        $end_date = inggris_date($ed);
        $data['master'] = $this->db->query("select status,b.Nip,b.positioncode,a.start_date,a.ApprovedBy,c.OutletCode,a.Approvedby,a.IdAttendanceA,a.Alokasi,a.keterangan,a.files,b.FullName
        from Attendance_Alokasi a left join employee b on a.Nip = b.Nip
        left join outlet c on b.OutletCode = c.OutletCode
        where flag = '1' and (start_date >= '".$start_date."' and start_date <= '".$end_date."') and a.Nip = '".$Nip."'")->result();
    $data['judul'] = "Sia";
    $view = "sia/index";
    $controller = "sia";
    $this->get_view($data,$view,$controller);         
     }
```

Now in client side. Following will alert `date_search` value you enter

```
function(data){
  //here you data is the return value from sia/index/`
   alert(data);
});
...
```

Comment: when i `alert(date)` the pop up result is like full html script.

Comment: Your `reservation` field is a input filed and read only. How `change` event working here?

Comment: I input this `05/03/2016 - 05/03/2016` and the result when `alert` is just like full script html (Like ctrl + u) if you open some website

Comment: I still can `alert (ids)`

Comment: when i `console.log(data);` . I have the right result

Comment: how to open `data`. because it have the result

Answer (score 0):

Check the first [example on jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) website:

```
$.post( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
    $( ".result" ).html( data );
});
```